# Combining raster textures with vector graphics. How can I do this? (See image)

Tags: vector-art, pixel-art

I'm developing an art style that combines pixel art with simple vector graphics, but I'm feeling lost and need clarity what is technically possible within game engines.

First of all, take a look at this image:
[image]

How can I achieve this look with game engines/libraries? Is it even possible?
What can you recommend?

The game is supposed to run on PC, 60fps preferable, uses pixel sprites for smaller objects, while using simple shapes to represent very large objects. I want it to have a lighting system, all shapes must be able to rotate, move and scale at runtime and have seamlessly tiling pixel art textures drawn on top of them.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with any graphics API or 3D engine/framework. Your vector graphics can be created from polygons, then you map a texture onto them.

Comment: Janos, you should post that or something similiar as the answer. I was going to answer the same, but it seems disingenious when you've already posted it in a comment.

Comment: I want to emphasize that lines, line edges and smooth, high performance circles are very important. Can polygons handle those?

My understanding is that is something only vector graphics can do.

Comment: *gah, not line edges. I meant to say line or edge width/thickness is also an important factor, that I don't know if polygons can provide.

Comment: What framework do you plan to use? The answer may depend on available techniques. Since you worry if polygons can provide this: yes, a box can be near infinitely this effctively resemble a line). A rectangle outline is basically four boxes used as a line (or two boxes, one textured and one used as a cutout. Again this depends on the available engine techniques.

Comment: @Felsir: Using polygonal rectangles as outlines... I didn't think of that. Huh. Sounds a bit of a hacky and performance heavy way to implement that, so I'm concerned about using that technique for a very vital part of the game. Still, knowing that such an option exist is valuable on its own too. Thank you for mentioning it! : )

Comment: It actually not that hacky, given that the GPU generally draws just triangles. I wouldn't worry about performance. Such a box would be about 8 triangles. Mobile games today can push a couple of thousands while desktops may push millions of triangles per frame.

Comment: Millions per frame... wow. That would be adequate actually. I went in thinking about vector graphics and how fit this together, but seems like its all triangles underneath it all. This changes a lot how I think about this now.

Thank you Felsir, your responses really cleared up some important information for me and I feel really happy that my need for progress was made on this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with any graphics API or 3D engine/framework. Your vector graphics can be created from polygons, then you map a texture onto them.

Comment: It's not *that* simple. Depending on the framework the polygon vertices need to map to texture coordinates, which in turn may lead to stretching. Using a shader for this is much more effective. However it depends on the framework or engine being used.

Comment: Using shader does no benefit. If you disagree, please post an answer explaining that statement.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing entirely. However the question did not contain a description of the intended engine/framework. If the OP plans to use monogame for example, you need to do more than just creating a polygon.

Comment: What about if line width as in the picture I posted? Can polygons have variable line width like vector graphics can?

Or smooth circles? With polygons I'm guessing a lot of triangles are needed to form just one circle, so it feels like they may be a bit too performance heavy. I really need a lot of circles in my game.

Comment: Again it depends on the engine you plan to use. Some do heavy lifting for you and allow you to specify the linewidth. Otherwise it would be two circles with r+0.5*width and r-0.5*width. I wouldn't worry about the triangles in general... AAA titles handle more 250.000 triangles for just one character. If you instance a circle on the GPU you can draw thousands of circles with little overhead. But again, it depends on your framework/engine how easy it is or how well this is supported.

Comment: Ok, that gives me a lot of confidence towards triangles. I now feel clear and got my need for understanding met with you mentioning those facts. Thank you Felsir!